# Why does this string concatenation loop not work?

Tags: c++, string, c++20

I want to use the formatting capabilites of the cstring library together with std::string's ability to dynamically allocate. Consider the following debug-log (I wouldn't do it in production code this way but for debugs cstring is convenient):

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:28,endLineNumber:19,positionColumn:28,positionLineNumber:19,selectionStartColumn:28,selectionStartLineNumber:19,startColumn:28,startLineNumber:19),source:%27%23include+%3Ccstdio%3E%0A%23include+%3Cstring%3E%0A%23include+%3Carray%3E%0A%23include+%3Ccstdint%3E%0A%23include+%3Ccstring%3E%0A%0Astd::array%3Cstd::pair%3Cuint32_t,+double%3E,+3%3E+list+%3D+%7B%7B%7B1,11.1%7D,+%7B2,22.2%7D,+%7B3,+33.3%7D%7D%7D%3B%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++std::string+start%3B%0A++++int+size+%3D+snprintf(NULL,+0,+%22array+(size%3D%25zu)%3B%22,+list.size())%3B%0A++++start.resize(size%2B1)%3B%0A++++snprintf(%26start.front(),+size%2B1,+%22array+(size%3D%25zu)%3B%22,+list.size())%3B%0A%0A++++for+(auto+%5Ba,b%5D+:+list)+%7B%0A++++++++std::string+tmp%3B%0A++++++++size+%3D+snprintf(NULL,+0,+%22array+(size%3D%25zu)%3B%22,+list.size())%3B%0A++++++++tmp.resize(size%2B1)%3B%0A++++++++snprintf(%26tmp.front(),+size%2B1,+%22%5Cn(%25u,+%25.2f)%3B%22,+a,+b)%3B%0A++++++++start+%2B%3D+tmp%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%0A++++printf(%22%25s%5Cn%22,+start.c_str())%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:66.07329842931937,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:gsnapshot,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27--std%3Dc%2B%2B20+-Wall+-Os%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+12.2%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:33.92670157068063,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
#include <array>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstring>

std::array<std::pair<uint32_t, double>, 3> list = {{{1,11.1}, {2,22.2}, {3, 33.3}}};

int main()
{
    std::string start;
    int size = snprintf(NULL, 0, "array (size=%zu);", list.size());
    start.resize(size+1);
    snprintf(&start.front(), size+1, "array (size=%zu);", list.size());

    for (auto [a,b] : list) {
        std::string tmp;
        size = snprintf(NULL, 0, "array (size=%zu);", list.size());
        tmp.resize(size+1);
        snprintf(&tmp.front(), size+1, "\n(%u, %.2f);", a, b);
        start += tmp;
    }

    printf("%s\n", start.c_str());
}
```

This doesn't work. It just prints the following:

```
array (size=3);
```

.. Instead of additionally printing each element. The loop runs however and if you emit the contents of tmp it shows that tmp actually stores the string mentioned. However, it doesn't seem to get attached to the `start` string the right way.

I suspect SSO gets in the way here, but I can't explain how. Afaik resize already preallocates on heap if buffer size is > 15 right? What am I overlooking?

Comment: It's not a great ideas to mix C-string and std::string processing together. For instance `snprintf(&start.front(), size+1, "array (size=%zu);", list.size());` can be replaced with `start += "array (size=" + std::to_string(list.size()) + ");";`

Comment: `size = snprintf(NULL, 0, "array (size=%zu);", list.size());` you are asking fdor the size of the string "array (size=xxx);" and then you are trying to write "\n(%u, %.2f);" which is different. Also from the docs: "The resulting character string will be terminated with a null character", which is not suitable for the string, because std::string internally is not terminated by NULL. Consider: `std::string s = "abc\0def"; std::cout << s.c_str() << std::endl;`

Comment: The issue is terminating null characters in `tmp` that get added in the middle of `start`. `snprintf` writes a terminator and I do not understand your way of calcualting `size`, though you can see the difference between number of characters in `start` (`size()`) and number of characters before the null terminator (`strlen(start.c_str()`): https://godbolt.org/z/era75cncz

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using a std::stringstream for this?

Comment: @dohashi "I want to use the formatting capabilites of the cstring library"

Comment: You've added tag `C++20` so why not use `std::format`?

Comment: @NathanOliver I'm suspicious of C++ way of handling strings, especially stringstream with its code bloat and overhead. I'm writing for an embedded system and I don't need that. I don't know about to_string, need to check that. What algo does to_string use for FP to string conversion?

Comment: @dohashi Because of binary bloat and runtime overhead

Comment: @glades `to_string` is required to produce output as if `snprintf` was used, so most implementations just use `snprintf` under the hood.  You can see the specifiers here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string

Comment: Try this experiment: replace `printf("%s\n", start.c_str());` with `std::cout << start << '\n';` -- any difference in output?

Comment: @NathanOliver I see, that makes everything easier

Comment: @JaMiT As I said iostream is off the table :) It would be easier yes

Comment: @glades As I said, "experiment". Not as a solution, but as a way to gain insight into what is going on. (If this was supposed to be a solution, I would make it an answer instead of a comment.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you have resized `start` more then it is needed. `std::string` is exception and actual buffer size is one item more then `size()` returns to contain terminating zero.

So `start` contains `"array (size=3);\0"` just before entering loop.

Now after each update (loop iteration) content is added after this extra `\0`.

So when you do `printf("%s\n", start.c_str());` it will stop printing on this zero. Extra content is there, but `printf` API is unable to reach it since encounters zero too soon.

You have also a typo with inconsistent format string.

[Fixed version](https://godbolt.org/z/1q11cr1Kj).

Comment: Oh I'm stupid x) Of course. Thanks

Comment: C++20 version https://godbolt.org/z/f9c6sanYn

Comment: Rather than resize `start` a bunch of times, you can loop twice: https://godbolt.org/z/11dzo8q4s

Comment: @Caleth Good input thank you